# Inconsistent object initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
struct RandomStruct {
  RandomStruct(int a) {

  }
}

int main() {
  RandomStruct works();
  RandomStruct doesntWork = RandomStruct();
  RandomStruct doesntWork2{};
}
```

Why is it that the second two intitializations don't work, but the first does? Should I use one form over another? This behaviour is rather bewildering to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Because the 1st one is a function declaration. Try `RandomStruct doesntWork3;`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, that makes a lot of sense. In this case is it correct to say that `RandomStruct works()` is simply incorrect, because C++ does not allow for function declarations inside functions?

Comment: No it's allowed. That's why it compiles fine.